# Possibility a child could genetically be also the child of its grandparent

Tags: genetics, human-genetics

When two people have sex, it is my understanding their diploid set of chromosomes is randomly split in half to create two haploid sets which unify into the diploid chromosome set of the child. For each parent, there are $2^{23}$ possible permutations or a chance of about 1 in 8 million. Let these two be the grandparents A and B, having a child C

When that child C has a new sex partner D and they make their own child E, in any case E shares half of its genetic makeup with both C and D (i.e., E is the child of C and D). However, with a probability of roughly 1:8000000, when halving C's diploid choromosome set, it always chose the A parts.

This means that E would then have a diploid set A+D, which would make E appear to be both the child of C but genetically could also be the child of A.

Is this understanding (discounting for crossing over and other genetics) generally correct? With a probability that high, if it is possible there should be recorded cases of this (although for all intents and purposes you would never know without sequencing DNA). Are there such cases?

Comment: But can we ever discount crossing over? Crossing over is a very consistent feature of meiosis. Perhaps what you say is possible for certain closely linked loci (e.g. HLA haplotypes). But it is hard to imagine for the entire chromosome complement of a sexually reproducing organism.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). Since this question "addresses a basic biology concept that may seem trivial to biology professionals", it qualifies as  ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework). In particular, you can't discount crossovers since they are essential. ——— Please take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: I have found that when learning about a new area starting with a relatively accessible and reliable source like [Khan Academy](http://khanacademy.org/science/biology/) is very helpful. Wikipedia is also generally a good starting point and you can then check their references. Online platforms called MOOCs offer free (or very low cost) courses on a wide variety of subjects — two I am familiar with are [Coursera](http://coursera.org) and [edX](http://edx.org). Finally, textbooks with a good level of detail are also freely available online e.g. from [NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/).

Answer (score 1):

One of the hallmark features of meiosis is the formation of [chiasmata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiasma_(genetics)), that is the crossing over and exchange of genetic information.
These structures are generally necesssary for a normal meiosis to happen and you should never get a cygote without any crossing over. Therefore, taking this into account, the probability of your scenario is 0.

Comment: I've been thinking some more about crossing over, and think it might not be an issue at all. In the 1:2^23 case, even with crossing over, the DNA would be mixed with some other, but would generally still appear to have both the actual parent and the grandparent as possible parents. Or would the crossing over make this always distinctively clear?

Comment: The crossig over in meiosis in the child (C) of the grandparents (A and B) means that all of the chromosomes will be a mixture of A and B. Therefore, the information to the subsequent child E cannot be purely A or B. There may be instances that on a particular chromosome where crossing occurs in a perfectly homologous region making it invisible. But for this to happen on every chromosome A and B would have to be perfect clones.

Answer (score 0):

I think this 1:8000000 should be further diminished twice by the chances to get "intact"(no cross-over) chromosome from A to C and from C to E. So the final probability is far less.